# MonoTouch, WCF, Large XML response, how to capture progress

Tags: wcf, mobile, xamarin.ios, behavior

I'm developing an app using MonoTouch and have to get some data from a 3rd party web service. I have a WCF binding to do such.

The particular web service method I am calling could potentially return an XML string in the range of several hundred megabytes, which could take a while to download to a mobile device.

I'm looking for some way to capture how many bytes have been read from the network at the system level, with the end-game being to display a progress indicator to the user. Is there some way I can achieve this using Behaviors?

Note, I don't have any way to modify the web service code to return a Stream object, which is what most of the articles I have found require doing.

Any help or direction would be much appreciated. Thanks

As a last resort, I can always fall back on using an NSURLConnection to do this, instead of WCF, because I know there are NSURLConnectionDelegate methods to hook into that will provide this. I wanted to avoid NSURLConnection, so that I will be able to easily drop this code into an Android project in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to use WCF instead of the plain HttpWebRequest?

WCF is not exactly efficient at parsing data, it will keep multiple copies in memory to deserialize the various chunks of information.

There is no system level API that can provide this information, the Stream that you get back from the HttpWebRequest is the best value that you will get.

Comment: Didn't even occur to me, actually. I'll have to generate the SOAP xml manually though, correct?